# Reddit Api via Snoowrap with Nextjs + TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript, next.js, reddit, react-typescript

I am using the [snoowrap](https://github.com/not-an-aardvark/snoowrap) library via not-an-aardvark to interact with reddits api. I want to implement a "fetch more" feature for users to load another 10 submissions if they wish via a fetch.fetchMore snoowrap helper function. These fetches are all authenticated OAuth snoowrap calls from the server using a configured `r` handler. This seems straightforward enough, but getting the unique id to populate the `after` key with is tricky. It requires the `author_fullname` (`t3_qesl`, for example) of the last index of the current submissions (posts) displayed to the user on a given subreddit thread. Here's one apporoach I've tried

```
    const snooSubs = await r
        .getNew(ctx.params ? ctx.params.display_name : 'snowboarding', {
            limit: 10,
            count: 10,
            show: 'all',
            after: (
                await r.getNew(ctx.params ? ctx.params.display_name : 'snowboarding', {
                    limit: 25,
                    count: 25,
                    show: 'all'
                })
            )
                .pop()?.author_fullname
        })
        .then(fetch => {
            fetch.fetchMore({
                amount: 10,
                append: true
            });
            return fetch;
        });
```

I tried using this embedded `pop` approach but that just got my credentials blacklisted for a short period by reddit while writing this post lol (apparently I exceeded the Reddit rate limit while writing this up of 9999 requests...). I currently am handling all r.getNew/getHot/etc requests within getStaticProps in both the index page and in a dynamically generated subroute `r/[display_name].tsx`. The only exception to this pattern being a serverless snooSearch file located in api routes that is pinged when a user searches for a given subreddit from the home page. At any rate, I was wondering if anyone has used snoowrap and next together, especially with typescript, and if so what their plan of attack was (whether it was similar or entirely different).

An aside, but I will mention that incremental static regeneration with server-side data-fetching in getStaticProps or serverless in api routes is an ideal strategy for performance and a superior user experience. So I'm avoiding client-side fetching as much as possible since the client can be fed server-generated/regenerated props via `InferGetStaticPropsType` -- all native Nextjs under the hood. I'll include a piece of the current flow I have below for clarities sake.

```
import {
    GetStaticPropsResult,
    InferGetStaticPropsType,
    GetStaticPropsContext,
    GetStaticPathsContext,
    GetStaticPathsResult
} from 'next';
import cn from 'classnames';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { r } from '@lib/snooConfig';
import { Params } from 'next/dist/next-server/server/router';
import Navbar from '@components/Navbar';
import Head from 'next/head';
import SubredditPost from '@components/Subreddit';
import {
    SkeletonSections,
    Logo,
    Container,
    Button
} from '@components/UI';
import NotFound from '@components/NotFound';
import {
    Submission,
} from 'snoowrap/dist/objects';
import {
    Serializer,
    JSONified
} from '../../types/json';
import { SubmissionTemplate } from '@components/Submission';
import { Meta } from '@components/Meta';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Loading = () => (
    <SkeletonSections>
        <div className='w-80 h-80 flex mx-auto items-center text-center justify-center p-3'>
            <Logo className='w-40 h-40 animate-pulse transform-gpu' />
        </div>
    </SkeletonSections>
);

export async function getStaticProps(
    ctx: GetStaticPropsContext
): Promise<
    GetStaticPropsResult<{
        submissionSerializer: string;
        post: {
            id: string;
            title: string;
            description: string;
            active_user_count: number;
            banner_img: string;
            created: any;
            description_html: string;
            public_description_html: string;
            url: string;
            banner_size: [number, number] | null;
            icon_size: [number, number] | null;
            display_name: string;
            display_name_prefixed: string;
            icon_img: string;
        }[];
    }>
> {
    const params = ctx.params as Params;
    const display_name = params.display_name as string;
    const snoo = await r.searchSubreddits({
        query: ctx!.params!.display_name as string,
        count: 10,
        limit: 1,
        show: 'all'
    });
    // get FullName to pass in as a variable in main getNew call
    const snooSubs = await r
        .getNew(display_name ? display_name : 'snowboarding', {
            limit: 25,
            count: 25,
            show: 'all',
            after: (
                await r.getNew(display_name, {
                    limit: 25,
                    count: 25,
                    show: 'all'
                })
            )
                .pop()
                ?.author_fullname.toString()
        })
        .then(fetch => {
            fetch.fetchMore({
                amount: 10,
                append: true
            });
            return fetch;
        });

    const snooComment = await r.getNewComments(
        ctx.params ? (ctx.params.display_name as string) : display_name
    );
    const post = snoo.map(mapped => {
        const {
            created,
            public_description_html,
            banner_img,
            active_user_count,
            description_html,
            icon_img,
            id,
            title,
            banner_size,
            url,
            icon_size,
            description,
            display_name_prefixed
        } = mapped;
        return {
            id,
            banner_size,
            display_name_prefixed,
            banner_img,
            description_html,
            public_description_html,
            title,
            icon_img,
            description,
            active_user_count,
            created,
            icon_size,
            url,
            display_name
        };
    });
    const snooSub = snooSubs.toJSON();
    const submissionSerializer = new Serializer<
        JSONified<Submission[]>
    >().serialize(snooSub);
    return {
        props: { submissionSerializer, post },
        revalidate: 10
    };
}

export async function getStaticPaths({
    locales
}: GetStaticPathsContext): Promise<
    GetStaticPathsResult<{
        path: string[];
        locale?: string;
    }>
> {
    const snoo = await r.searchSubreddits({
        query: locales ? locales[0] as string : 'snowboarding',
        count: 25,
        limit: 1
    });
    return {
        paths: locales
            ? locales.reduce<string[]>((arr, locale) => {
                    //add a subreddit path for each locale
                    snoo.forEach(post => {
                        arr.push(`/${locale}/${post.display_name_prefixed}`);
                    });
                    return arr;
              }, [])
            : snoo.map(post => `/${post.display_name_prefixed}`),
        fallback: true
    };
}

export default function DisplayName({
    submissionSerializer,
    post
}: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) {
    const m: Submission[] = JSON.parse(submissionSerializer);
    console.log(m);

    const isVideo = (
        <Container>
            {m ? (
                m.map(img => {
                    const { post_hint, stickied, is_video, media } = img;
                    return is_video === true &&
                        stickied !== true &&
                        post_hint !== 'self' &&
                        media != null &&
                        media.reddit_video != null &&
                        media.reddit_video.fallback_url != null &&
                        media.reddit_video.scrubber_media_url != null &&
                        media.reddit_video.height != null ? (
                        <div className='flex flex-grow mx-auto w-full align-middle'>
                            <ul className='divid-y- divide-gray-200'>
                                <li className='px-4 py-4 sm:px-0'>
                                    <audio>
                                        <video
                                            autoPlay
                                            controls={true}
                                            controlsList='volume'
                                            loop
                                            muted={false}
                                            playsInline
                                            src={
                                                media.reddit_video.fallback_url ??
                                                media.reddit_video.scrubber_media_url ??
                                                ''
                                            }
                                            height={media.reddit_video.height}
                                            width={500}
                                            className='w-auto rounded-sm col-span-1'
                                        />
                                    </audio>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <></>
                    );
                })
            ) : (
                <></>
            )}
        </Container>
    );
    console.log(submissionSerializer);
    const router = useRouter();
    const { query } = useRouter();
    const [activeUsers] = m.map(s => {
        const active = s.subreddit_subscribers;
        return {
            active
        };
    });

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>{`${
                    m
                        ? m.map(o => '/' + o.subreddit_name_prefixed)
                        : (query.display_name as string)
                }`}</title>
            </Head>
            <Meta />
            <Navbar />
            {router.isFallback ? (
                <Loading />
            ) : (
                <>
                    {post ? (
                        post.map(p => {
                            return (
                                <>
                                    <SubredditPost
                                        icon_size={p.icon_size}
                                        banner_size={p.banner_size}
                                        banner_img={p.banner_img}
                                        icon_img={p.icon_img}
                                        public_description_html={p.public_description_html}
                                        title={p.title}
                                        description_html={p.description_html}
                                        display_name_prefixed={'/' + p.display_name_prefixed}
                                        active_user_count={activeUsers.active.toLocaleString()}
                                        id={p.id}
                                        description={p.description ?? ''}
                                        display_name={p.display_name}
                                    >
                                        {m ? (
                                            m.map(sub => {
                                                const { media } = sub;
                                                return media !== null &&
                                                    media.reddit_video !== null &&
                                                    media.reddit_video !== undefined &&
                                                    media.reddit_video.dash_url !== undefined &&
                                                    media.reddit_video.fallback_url !== undefined &&
                                                    media.reddit_video.scrubber_media_url !==
                                                        undefined ? (
                                                    <>
                                                        <SubmissionTemplate
                                                            thumbnail={
                                                                sub.thumbnail !== 'self' ? sub.thumbnail : '/ts-placeholder.png'
                                                            }
                                                            thumbnail_height={sub.thumbnail_height}
                                                            thumbnail_width={sub.thumbnail_width}
                                                            title={sub.title}
                                                            selftext={sub.selftext}
                                                            selftext_html={sub.selftext_html}
                                                            ups={sub.ups}
                                                            media_embed={isVideo}
                                                            post_hint={sub.post_hint}
                                                            is_reddit_media_domain={
                                                                sub.is_reddit_media_domain
                                                            }
                                                            is_video={sub.is_video}
                                                            is_self={sub.is_self}
                                                            stickied={sub.stickied}
                                                            scrubber_media_url={
                                                                media.reddit_video.scrubber_media_url
                                                            }
                                                            dash_url={media.reddit_video.dash_url}
                                                            fallback_url={media.reddit_video.fallback_url}
                                                            is_gif={media.reddit_video.is_gif}
                                                            transcoder_status={
                                                                media.reddit_video.transcoding_status
                                                            }
                                                            height={media.reddit_video.height}
                                                        />
                                                        <div className='mx-auto py-6'>{fetching}</div>
                                                    </>
                                                ) : (
                                                    <></>
                                                );
                                            })
                                        ) : (
                                            <></>
                                        )}
                                    </SubredditPost>
                                </>
                            );
                        })
                    ) : (
                        <NotFound />
                    )}
                </>
            )}
        </>
    );
}
```

That's it for the `pages/r/[display_name].tsx` subpage. That's where I am trying to implement the load more functionality. Any thoughts, or outside the snoobox ideas would be appreciated. I'll throw my helper types in below as a bonus for reading through a somewhat longwinded post. Cheers.

```
// types/json.ts
import {
    Subreddit,
    Submission,
    Comment
} from 'snoowrap/dist/objects';
export class Serializer<T> {
    serialize(inp: T): string {
        return JSON.stringify(inp);
    }
    deserialize(inp: string): JSONified<T> {
        return JSON.parse(inp);
    }
}
/**
 * @toJSON (): Obj ? JSON.stringify uses Obj returned from toJSON for serialization :
 * JSON.stringify uses the actual properties
 */

export type Widget = {
    toJSON(): {
        kind: 'Widget';
        date: Date;
    };
};

export type Item = {
    text: string;
    count: number;
    // preserve options
    choice: 'yes' | 'no' | null;
    // drop functions
    func: () => void;
    nested: {
        isSaved: boolean;
        data: [1, undefined, 2];
    };
    // pointer to another type
    widget: Widget;
    // Same obj referenced again
    children?: Item[];
};

export type JSONified<T> = JSONifiedValue<
    T extends { toJSON(): infer U } ? U : T
>;

export type JSONifiedValue<T> = T extends
    | string
    | number
    | boolean
    | null
    ? T
    : T extends Function
    ? never
    : T extends object
    ? JSONifiedObject<T>
    : T extends Array<infer U>
    ? JSONifiedArray<U>
    : never;

export type JSONifiedObject<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: JSONifiedObject<T[P]>;
};

/**
 * element === undefined ?
 * JSON.stringify maps JSONified undefined to null via recursion :
 * JSONified.contains(element === undefined) ? JSONifiedArray maps nested undefined to null
 */
export type UndefinedAsNull<T> = T extends undefined ? null : T;

export type JSONifiedArray<T> = Array<
    UndefinedAsNull<JSONified<T>>
>;
```